# vim macro replacing \n with ','

Tags: vim, macros

I am trying to save a macro which replaces `\n` with `,`

Input:

```
978818
978818
900298
900272
```

Output:

```
'978818','978818','900298','900272'
```

When I saved the macro using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd> in vimrc it looks like below:

```
let @b = ":%s/\n/','/g^MI'^[A~@kb~@kb^["
```

But now when I run this macro it give the output as:

```
978818978818900298900272
```

and error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: ','
```

Don't know why it is trying to match `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to escape the \n. vim thinks you want a new line character at that point in the string and replaces it with a literal new line. So the fixed macro should be.

`let @b = ":%s/\\n/','/g^MI'^[A~@kb~@kb^["`

Edit: If you want something that you can copy and paste-able I believe the macro below is equivalent to what you want.

`let @b = ":%s/\\n/','/g\nI'\e$xx"`

Comment: Sorry, but this also doesn't seem to work. it just prints the whole macro as it is in the command space

Comment: did you copy and paste it? `^M` and `^[` are special characters in vim. These can not be copied and pasted. All you need to do add another ``\`` in front of the `\n` in your original macro.